# Using OpenVPN and iptables in combination

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openvpn

Let's imagine there are three networks, WAN, LAN-A and LAN-B. In between, there is a firewall server connecting the networks to each other. iptables ensures the following things:

- There is no way for external WAN-users to access both local networks
- users in LAN-A can access LAN-B via the firewall, but...
- users in LAN-B can't access LAN-A

The firewall machine uses iptables for routing and filtering and, at the same time, acts an an OpenVPN server.

I want users from outside to connect to LAN-A and LAN-B via VPN. The first idea is to allow the firewall's tun0-interface to establish connections to LAN-A and LAN-B via let's say eth1 and eth2 (eth0 is used for the internet connection).

A theoretical question: would it be sufficient to allow VPN connections only to LAN-A via eth1 and omit explicit rules for accessing LAN-B? According to above, it is possible to access LAN-B if you are in LAN-A anyway, so I'm not sure if there is a need for allowing tun0 to access LAN-B.

A second question: is tun0 part of the three networks directly or is it isolated within the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your OpenVPN will reside on your router/firewall, no, it is not enough to allow access from VPN only to LAN-A. When a user connected to OpenVPN wants to access LAN-B, he will send packets to IP address in LAN-B. Packets on router/firewall machine will be destined to IP residing behind interface eth2 (assuming eth1 connects to LAN-A and eth2 to LAN-B). If you don't allow traffic from tun0 to go through eth2, those packets would get dropped at the firewall. There is no need for them to go to LAN-A at all.

Regarding your second question - tun0 will be part of the three networks - for example: all the computers from LAN-A will be able to ping tun0 address, and will be able to access machines connected to OpenVPN - unless you filter that traffic. Same applies for LAN-B.